# query returning different table when php changed from 7.2.1 to 7.1.12

Tags: php, mysql

I'm changing between **PHP** 7.1.12 and 7.2.1 on my `localhost` (MAMP) so I can update my PHP accordingly to ensure nothing has broken. I have come across a strange problem where when I change between the two versions, I get different results from the **SQL** query.

---

Here's an example (same **SQL** query for all instances):

```
SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE upload_artist IN (SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower = x) ORDER BY upload_id
```

**PHP** 7.1.12 returns:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (...) {
    ["user_id"]=> string(1) "6", etc...
}
```

Whereas **PHP** 7.2.1 returns (notice how it says `"upload_id"` instead of `"user_id"`) [**THIS IS THE CORRECT OUTPUT**]:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (...) {
    ["upload_id"]=> string(1) "3", etc...
}
```

---

Both **PHP** versions are using the same flavour of **MySQL** and are on the same machine, using the same host. What is causing this to happen and how can I fix it?

Cheers.

Comment: It is a object so the order of "upload_id","user_id" may get changed on using var_dump(). Still you can access the values using
$object->user_id, $object->upload_id which makes no difference.

Comment: @balakrishnan no, you cannot.

Comment: Can you post full result replacing etc.. so can see what is happening.

Comment: @balakrishnan the results are just the corresponding tables. `user_id` means the `users` table was returned, and `upload_id` means the `uploads` table was returned.